# Why game roms are lighter than their original version?

Tags: roms

I would like to know if you could help me with this question , I was wondering

Why the rom made of a videogame is ligther than the game itself or an indie game of today? I mean a rom can be 20mb while an indie game can be 200mb! An Snes rom, GBA or even a ds file is lighter than an actual game of today... why is this? why old videogames roms were so ligth but yet finished?

How can I make a game like that: complete but light? 
Thank you!

Comment: There are a ton of reasons for this; this question doesn't really suit our site as it's about actual game development. Just a few: sound files are now high-quality samples. Visual assets are now much higher resolution. Game engines come with a lot of extra size; a Unity game with no game is 65 MB on iOS.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not really about game development.

Comment: Almo listed a couple of great reasons. Resources such as graphics (2D images or 3D models) and audio make up the biggest portion of a game. Older game systems imposed limits on these resources to keep them small. A modern image file could use up to 32 bits per pixel (RGBA), whereas the NES used 2 bits per pixel combined with a palette. Modern audio is stored as waveforms with up to 96000 samples per second of up to 24 bits per sample, whereas the NES simply stores parameters to drive its waveform generators.

Comment: Ohh I seee I apologyze for placing the question here. Im sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's mostly because of the assets. Audio was only a couple of kilobytes at most, because there was no space for it. Old games didn't have enough memory to store the screen completely, thus they had to make a compromise. The screen was divided into 8x8 blocks, each of them could have 2 or 4 colors depending on the system (the original NES used 4 for example). The color of sprites where separate from this.

You can notice this very easily, if you look at Super Mario Bros 3 for the NES you'll never see more than 4 colors in a tile and this is the same reason the right edge had a strange color.

Because of this, a single sprite could be represented in 17 bytes (16 for the image, 1 for the color palette). If you take a modern format and make an image with a similar size, you'll get a lot bigger size (120bytes with a PNG for instance). This overhead is present in almost every format.

We also started using a lot bigger images, the sprite sheet of Super Mario could probably fit in a 512 x 512 image, while a single modern texture is bigger than that.

Also, old games weren't 3 dimensional. Storing a model takes up a huge space. Same with game engines. Old games simply couldn't use one, because the code had to fit on the cartridge, and they also introduce a huge overhead in file size.

Comment: As a side note, there are ways to make very small games, but these are intentionally small. For example the whole js13kgames competition revolves around this

Comment: Another relevant factor is that back in the cartridge age, ROM space was expensive. If you needed a larger ROM chip, your cartridge was more expensive to manufacture, which reduced your profit margin. So game developers were encouraged to conserve space. But nowadays where most games are distributed digitally and bandwidth is cheap, filesize became much less relevant.